# Parallel computing on graph-like structure

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

I am working on the development of [openBF](https://github.com/INSIGNEO/openBF) which is a finite-volume solver for blood flow in elastic vessels (i.e. arteries). In the code, arterial networks are represented as directed graphs that may also contain closed loops (anastomosis). The solver marches in space starting from an inlet node towards multiple outlet nodes. My idea is to  use multiple workers to solve in parallel vessels starting from the same node (bifurcation).

Here's an example of bifurcating network
[image: bifurcating network] 
Nodes number is reported in the circles and vessels number is on the arrows. The dashed lines separate the groups of elements that can be computed in parallel. Simply, a worker solves equation for one vessel and for the node at the end of the vessel. In the case of root vessel, also the inlet node is solved.

I implemented this in parallel by using `@everywhere`, `@spawn`, and `fetch()`. This is working fine, [here](https://gist.github.com/alemelis/8971804b09147b3c99c29be91ebfdfe2)'s a toy-example and this is the output

```
Inlet vessel #1
Solve vessel #1
Bifurcation at node 2 between vessels 1, 2, and 3
From worker 3:  Solve vessel #3
From worker 2:  Solve vessel #2
From worker 2:  Junction at node 3 between vessels 2 and 4
From worker 4:  Solve vessel #4
From worker 3:  Junction at node 4 between vessels 3 and 8
From worker 5:  Solve vessel #8
From worker 4:  Junction at node 5 between vessels 4 and 5
From worker 5:  Bifurcation at node 8 between vessels 8, 9, and 12
From worker 5:  Solve vessel #5
From worker 4:  Solve vessel #9
From worker 8:  Solve vessel #12
From worker 8:  Bifurcation at node 10 between vessels 12, 13, and 14
From worker 4:  Bifurcation at node 9 between vessels 9, 10, and 11
From worker 9:  Solve vessel #13
From worker 7:  Solve vessel #10
From worker 6:  Solve vessel #11
From worker 8:  Solve vessel #14
From worker 5:  Junction at node 6 between vessels 5 and 7
From worker 9:  Outlet vessel #13 - Compute outlet BC
From worker 9:  Solve vessel #7
From worker 7:  Outlet vessel #10 - Compute outlet BC
From worker 8:  Outlet vessel #14 - Compute outlet BC
From worker 6:  Outlet vessel #11 - Compute outlet BC
From worker 9:  Outlet vessel #7 - Compute outlet BC
```

My problems start when I add also closed loops as below
[image: anastomosis network]
Here the new vessel (6) links nodes 4 and 6 creating a shortcut to reach vessel 7. Given the mathematical model nature, I cannot solve node 6 before solving vessels 5 and 6.

I tried to solve this problem by adding a `solved` flag for each vessel (in the real code, the vessel has a struct containing various information). [Here](https://gist.github.com/alemelis/f0cfc6a19ef5a75d0669d4afef304b1d)'s the second toy-example. I added a check on the `solved` flag and iff the two converging vessels have `solved=1`, the anastomosis node can be solved. However, it seems that my data struct is not shared between the various workers as the example output shows

```
Inlet vessel #1
Solve vessel #1
Bifurcation at node 2 between vessels 1, 2, and 3
From worker 5:  Solve vessel #3
From worker 4:  Solve vessel #2
From worker 4:  Junction at node 3 between vessels 2 and 4
From worker 8:  Solve vessel #4
From worker 5:  Bifurcation at node 4 between vessels 3, 6, and 8
From worker 2:  Solve vessel #8
From worker 5:  Solve vessel #6
From worker 8:  Junction at node 5 between vessels 4 and 5
From worker 6:  Solve vessel #5
From worker 2:  Bifurcation at node 8 between vessels 8, 9, and 12
From worker 4:  Solve vessel #9
From worker 5:  Converging vessels solved? 0 1
From worker 6:  Converging vessels solved? 1 0
From worker 6:  Solve vessel #12
From worker 4:  Bifurcation at node 9 between vessels 9, 10, and 11
From worker 7:  Solve vessel #10
From worker 4:  Solve vessel #11
From worker 7:  Outlet vessel #10 - Compute outlet BC
From worker 6:  Bifurcation at node 10 between vessels 12, 13, and 14
From worker 5:  Solve vessel #13
From worker 9:  Solve vessel #14
From worker 4:  Outlet vessel #11 - Compute outlet BC
From worker 9:  Outlet vessel #14 - Compute outlet BC
From worker 5:  Outlet vessel #13 - Compute outlet BC
```

When it says `From worker 5: Converging vessels solved? 0 1` the code is actually printing the  value of solved for vessels 5 and 6 (and same for the following line).

Is this the case where I should use a `SharedArray` rather than the macro `@everywhere` when defining my struct?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: **Q1:** What is your principal motivation for introducing any parallelism into the pure-[SERIAL] process-scheduling solver-governed domain? **Q2:** What is the future-value of your set of expectations from undertaking all such process-re-engineering associated efforts? ( quantitatively express both the former and the latter ) **Q3:** What amount of [man*days] ( efforts ) are you ready to spend to achieve both 1 + 2? **Q4:** What fraction of [3] have you + your team colleagues already spent on problem analyses, prototyping and testing ( before asking here, at StackOverflow )?

Comment: @user3666197 

**A1**: The ultimate use of the solver is for Monte Carlo analysis (thousands of simulations) of rather large networks (200+ vessels). Therefore, the parallel version is something we want to look into.

**A2** A rough back-of-the-envelope calculation indicates that a parallel execution with ~8 workers would halve the total computational time. Each simulation can last up to 1 hour. For 350k simulations, in an imbarassingle parallel scenario with 100 nodes allocated, this would take 48 days. In the parallel case this is 24 days.

Comment: @user3666197 **A3**: There's not a deadline for this. The MC runs will be done anyway. **A4**: We have been working on this since August.

Comment: It sounds like using a SharedArray could be a good model

Comment: @MichaelK.Borregaard I agree but it seems that SharedArray elements must be bits types, not Any. This is a problem as I am using a custom type for my calculations.